# django-role-permissions does not work with transactions?

Tags: python, django, django-role-permissions

I am struggling with the following issue for a few days now.
The application uses django-role-permissions. Unit tests do not work correctly. Here is the example code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rolepermissions.roles import AbstractUserRole


class FooRole(AbstractUserRole):
    available_permissions = {
        "foo": "bar"
    }


user = User.objects.create(username="abc")
with transaction.atomic():
    role = FooRole.assign_role_to_user(user)
```

When running the test, the following happens when trying to assign role to user:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.Group.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.    
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1305, 'SAVEPOINT s4598857152_x2 does not exist')
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

**EDIT**